# Notepad ++ Plugin Installation Issues

Tags: plugins, notepad++

I'm using Notepad ++ version 7.6.3

I'm trying to install the Poor Man's T-SQL Formatter Plugin in Notepad ++ via the Plugin Manager.

I was able to install the Plugin Manager no problem through the plugin admin. I then installed Poor Man's T-SQL via the plugin manager. However it does not appear in the Plugin options. (Image 1)

[image: Image 1]

However when I go into the Plugin Manger its says that it is installed. (Image 2)

[image]

Does anybody know how I can use this plugin? Anything I have read online tells me how to install plugin manager but I already have this installed?

It is also worth noting that all the necessary files are appearing in the correct directory.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Finally figured it out after playing around and searching through the subfolders.

One of the dll files somehow installed outside the PoorMansTSqlFormatterNppPlugin directory.

There was an additional dll file called PoorMansTSqlFormatterNppPlugin.dll that needed to be moved into this directory.